# Why is a subclass constructor undefined in its parent class?

Tags: java, constructor, interface, subclass, abstract

I have a problem here that is probably very simple to solve, but unfortunately I'm still a bit stumped.

```
public final class ImmutableMap<K, V> extends AbstractReadableMap<K, V>  
{
    public ImmutableMap(Entry<K, V>[] entry)
    {
        super();
    }
}
```

I have this class **ImmutableMap<K, V>** and its constructor.

```
public interface ReadableMap<K, V> 
{ 
   public abstract ImmutableMap<K, V> asImmutableMap();
}
```

I have this interface **ReadableMap<K, V>** and its abstract method asImmutableMap.

```
public abstract class AbstractReadableMap<K, V> implements ReadableMap<K, V> 
{
  protected Entry<K, V>[] entries;

  public  ImmutableMap<K, V> asImmutableMap()
          {
              return ImmutableMap(entries);
          }
}
```

And finally I have this class **AbstractReadableMap<K, V>** where I'd like to implement the method asImmutableMap(). Unfortunately I get the error *The method ImmutableMap(Entry<K,V>[]) is undefined for the type AbstractReadableMap<K,V>*.

```
public class Launcher 
{
    

        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            MutableMap<String, Integer> map = new MutableMap<String, Integer>();
            putEntries(map);
            printEntries(map);
            ImmutableMap<String, Integer> immutableMap = asImmutableMap(map);
            printEntries(immutableMap);
        }
}
```

Same here: *The method asImmutableMap(MutableMap<String,Integer>) is undefined for the type Launcher*

Why is that and how can I fix it?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: You forgot the `new` keyword. You also forgot the diamond. It should look like `return new ImmutableMap<>(entries)`. And the only method named `asImmutableMap` in the code you've shown takes zero arguments, yet you're passing `map` to it.

Comment: Oh yeah you're right. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Regarding your second error, I assume you meant `map.asImmutableMap()` instead of `asImmutableMap(map)`.

Comment: Yes, that was it. I just tried it and it works now.